# How to get data from datasource with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Okey, please be patience. I only know jquery and I heard that use AngularJS is something that I should try.

So, what I need to to is visit a page on my local host `"../asp/fases/fases-controler.asp"` 
parse the json that this page shows me (   that is something like this: `{ "fasekind": [ "AAA", "BBB", "CCC" ] }`   ) and then mount on client side a list like this:

```
<ul>
   <li><input type="checkbox" /> <label>AAA</label></li>
   <li><input type="checkbox" /> <label>BBB</label></li>
   <li><input type="checkbox" /> <label>CCC</label></li>
</ul>
```

I do need a help with this. I only know the jQuery way. I have seen so many tutorials but I don't get it. I receive always  `Uncaught ReferenceError: $http is not defined` and other erros messages.

I don't want someone to do that for me, I just need to figure out how it works.

js controller that I try... it does not work at all.

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("AppCtrl", function ($http) {
    var app = this;
    $http.get("../asp/fases/fases-controler.asp")
        .success(function (data) {
            app.fases = data;
        })

})
```

Comment: Where is your js/contoller code?

Comment: var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("AppCtrl", function ($http) {
    var app = this;
    $http.get("../asp/fases/fases-controler.asp")
        .success(function (data) {
            app.fases = data;
        })

})

Comment: @UderMoreira Please do not use comments to add additional code. Edit your question if needed. Anyway, going through the angular docs and following some official tutorials is a way to go.

Comment: I found an answer [here][1], it was missing the JSON parse.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917238/problems-parsing-a-json-response-using-angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CONTROLLER**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("AppCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {

    $http.get("../asp/fases/fases-controler.asp")
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.fases = data;
        });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid-12-12" ng-app='currentApp' ng-controller='ACtrl'>
    <label>Fases <em class="formee-req">*</em>
    </label>
    <ul class="formee-list">
        <li ng-repeat="list in fases">
            <input name="checkbox-01" type="checkbox" />
            <label>{{list}}</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/Yt62s/)**

Comment: i got http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.7/ng/areq?p0=ACtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

Comment: Now i have http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.7/ng/areq?p0=AppCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

Comment: Do you have the exact same controller and html I posted?

Comment: html little bit diferent:         <div class="grid-12-12" ng-app='app' ng-controller='AppCtrl'>
                <label>Fases <em class="formee-req">*</em></label>
                <ul class="formee-list">
                    <li ng-repeat="list in fases">
                     <input name="checkbox-01" type="checkbox" /> <label>{{list}}</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </div>

Comment: Any luck yet? @UderMoreira

Comment: Nothing yet. http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.7/ng/areq?p0=AppCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

Comment: @UderMoreira what is your `ng-controller` in your html? And what the name of your controller? These are basic errors

Comment: ng-app='currentApp' ng-controller='AppCtrl'. The controler (js) is equal as the answer.

Comment: Ok, the error is self explanatory really. I can't really help you anymore. Unless you create a jsfiddle

Comment: which object does the http create? I pass a URL, so in the response, wicht is the object? in your fidle you have create var obj.

Comment: so, var obj = promise is valid?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917238/problems-parsing-a-json-response-using-angularjs), it was missing the JSON parse I guess. This is what I did:

**JSON**

```
{
  "fasekind": [ 
              "AAA",
              "BBB",
              "CCC" 
              ]
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
function FetchCtrl($scope, $http) {
        $scope.url = 'fases/fases-controler.asp';

        $http.get($scope.url).success(function (data, status) {
            $scope.fasekind = data.fasekind;
        }).error(function (data, status) {
                $scope.response = 'Request failed';
            });
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="grid-12-12" ng-controller='FetchCtrl'>
        <label>Fases <em class="formee-req">*</em>
        </label>
        <ul class="formee-list">
            <li ng-repeat="foo in fasekind">
                <input name="checkbox-01" type="checkbox" />
                <label>{{foo}}</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```