# AngularJS Unexpected String

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

following an example in an Angular book, and they have the following code:

```
<script>
   var test = {};


   var app = angular.module("app",[]);

   app.run(function($http){
      $http.get("/file").success(function(data){
         test.input = data;
      });
   });

   app.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
      $scope.handle = test;
   });


</script>
```

presumably data is pulled from file, pushed to the object 'test', which is then put into the scope's handle variable.  The problem when I write this up, however, is that the $http.get:

```
   app.run(function($http){
      $http.get("/file").success(function(data){
         test = data;
      });
   });
```

is producing the following error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected string
>       at Object.parse (native)
>       at vc (http://localhost/common/js/frameworks/angular.min.js:15:480)
>       at Zb (http://localhost/common/js/frameworks/angular.min.js:82:229)
>       at http://localhost/common/js/frameworks/angular.min.js:83:143
>       at m (http://localhost/common/js/frameworks/angular.min.js:7:322)
>       at dd (http://localhost/common/js/frameworks/angular.min.js:83:125)
>       at d (http://localhost/common/js/frameworks/angular.min.js:84:380)
>       at http://localhost/common/js/frameworks/angular.min.js:119:113
>       at n.a.$get.n.$eval (http://localhost/common/js/frameworks/angular.min.js:133:221)
>       at n.a.$get.n.$digest (http://localhost/common/js/frameworks/angular.min.js:130:233)
>   (anonymous function)     b.$get      (anonymous function)
>   a.$get.n.$eval       a.$get.n.$digest    a.$get.n.$apply     h       K
>   z.onload

which, to me, indicates that $http is not expecting a string url.  Could someone explain this to me?  Is the book's sample code wrong, or perhaps out of date?

edit:

the /file contents are as follows:

> [{"a":"1","b":"2"},{"aa":"3","bb":"4"}]

edit 2:

From other SO articles [Problems parsing a JSON response using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917238/problems-parsing-a-json-response-using-angularjs) it looks like $http.get is supossed to be auto parsing

Comment: Can you tell us the contents of `/file`? Because I believe `/file` isn't what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should encode the data. and the error will disappear:

```
'[{"a":"1","b":"2"},{"aa":"3","bb":"4"}]'
```

Comment: what file is it `.php` or just a`. json` file?

Comment: so try to do it as I posted, and let me know if you still encounter the error.

Comment: so the error disappeared and i checked, the information is at least transferring, but I had 2 issues:  First, I was under the impression it can accept json.  The second, is the quotes are copying as well, which doesnt make it a valid JSON object when transferred.  seems kinda hacky to look for quotes at the beginning and end and remove them just to parse it

Comment: another odd issue is that with an auto-refresh it will show ass i type in {{handle}}, then when i refresh the content disappears

Comment: you can use JSON too, something like: `{"recs": [{"a":"1","b":"2"},{"aa":"3","bb":"4"}]}`, and then in your function you fetch `data.recs`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94666/discussion-between-shim-br-and-david-torrey).